# Shopware 6: Remove PayPal cart warning

Tags: shopware

The off-canvas cart shows "The payment method PayPal is blocked for your current shopping cart." / "Die Zahlungsart PayPal ist für Ihren aktuellen Warenkorb gesperrt."

How do I remove this warning?

If the cart is 0€ I don't want to show PayPal at all.

I found a [solution in the forum](https://forum.shopware.com/t/paypal-neuer-fehler/67509/8) using the "Always valid (default)" rule but this does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning is shown if the customer has selected PayPal as payment method in this account see `/account/payment`. In my very special case I solved it by resetting all customer payments to another payment:

```
UPDATE customer SET default_payment_method_id = X'C6139B2C8E8541028EEFCC2D60D80820'
```